# Python gives KeyError while the key is passed

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am trying to create different python file where the code is given below. While calling the method, I pass the mydata as data frame with these columns
['wage', 'educ', 'exper', 'tenure'].

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from prettytable import PrettyTable as pt

def LinearRegressionOLS(mydata,target_column):

    if(not isinstance(mydata,pd.DataFrame)):
        raise TypeError("Data must be of type Data Frame")

    if(not isinstance(target_column,str)):
        raise TypeError("target_column must be String")

    if(target_column not in mydata.columns):
        raise KeyError("target_column doesn't exist in Data Frame")

    data=mydata.copy()

    data["one"]=np.ones(data.count()[target_column])

    column_list=["one"]
    for i in data.columns:
        column_list.append(i)

    Y=data[target_column].as_matrix()
    data.drop(target_column,inplace=True,axis=1)
    X=data[column_list].as_matrix()
    del data

    beta = np.matmul(np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(X.T,X)),X.T),Y)
    predY = np.matmul(X,beta)
    total = np.matmul((Y-np.mean(Y)).T,(Y-np.mean(Y)))
    residual = np.matmul((Y-predY).T,(Y-predY))
    sigma = np.matmul((Y-predY).T,(Y-predY))/(X.shape[0]-X.shape[1])
    omega = np.square(sigma)*np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(X.T,X))
    SE = np.sqrt(np.diag(omega))
    tstat = beta/SE
    Rsq = 1-(residual/total)

    final = pt()
    final.add_column(" ",column_list)
    final.add_column("Coefficients",beta)
    final.add_column("Standard Error",SE)
    final.add_column("t-stat",tstat)

    print(final)
    print("Residual: ",residual)
    print("Total: ",total)
    print("Standard Error: ",sigma)
    print("R Square: ",Rsq)
```

After running the above code, by calling the function given below,

```
    >>> c
    ['wage', 'educ', 'exper', 'tenure']
    >>> import LR_OLS as inf
    >>> inf.LinearRegressionOLS(file[c],"wage")
```

, i get some error like this

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#182>", line 1, in <module>
        inf.LinearRegressionOLS(file[c],"wage")
    File "E:\python\LR_OLS.py", line 29, in LinearRegressionOLS
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2133, in __getitem__
        return self._getitem_array(key)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2177, in _getitem_array
        indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1269, in _convert_to_indexer
        .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
    KeyError: "['wage'] not in index"
```

Can anyone help me as to why i am getting this error. How can i resolve it?

Comment: Remove all these tests at the beginning of the function. Errors are automatically raised, if something goes wrong.

Comment: The most important line of the traceback is missing: line 29.

Comment: I dont understand...i havent removed any lines from the traceback

Comment: well it is saying that wage is not in index, so my thought might fall to:  file[c] doesnt have a key, Wage?

Comment: I have mentioned above, wage is being passed in the data frame as well as the argument

Comment: As `c` looks like a list, `file[c]` should not be possible.

Comment: >>> file.columns
  Index(['wage', 'educ', 'exper', 'tenure', 'nonwhite', 'female', 'married',
   'numdep', 'smsa', 'northcen', 'south', 'west', 'construc', 'ndurman',
   'trcommpu', 'trade', 'services', 'profserv', 'profocc', 'clerocc',
   'servocc', 'lwage', 'expersq', 'tenursq'],
   dtype='object')
  
  >>> file[c].columns
  Index(['wage', 'educ', 'exper', 'tenure'], dtype='object')

Comment: Where do you define `file`?

Comment: file is defined in my console as
file = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv")

Comment: It's not clear from your question what relevance the code you pasted has on your errors. Can you clean up the question and clarify what `file` looks like?

Comment: file is a data frame which has be defined as file = pandas.read_csv("file_name.csv"), file_name.csv has 26 more or less columns which i have mentioned in the above comments.Since i only need to work with 4 columns i have defined a list c which contains the column names mentioned above and I am passing this data frame to the function that has been mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you still have `'wage'` in `'column_list`. So in order to never let it get in there do the following adaptation:

```
for i in data.columns:
    if i != 'wage':  # add this line to your code
       column_list.append(i)
```